# Разрешить нажимать на кнопку раз в 15 минут

Tags: php, jquery

Как реализовать через куки с отсчетом времени после нажатия на кнопку что бы в течении 15 минут не было возможности нажать.

Желательно решение на php либо jquery но я думаю jquery можно обойти.

Comment: А где ваше решение, или хотя бы ход мысли?

Comment: Ход мысли такой, есть кнопка. Я на нее нажимаю при нажатии у меня происходит какое либо действие. После того как я нажал, в течении допустим 30 минут я не могу нажать на кнопку. Типа идет запрет на нажатие

Comment: Это не ход мысли, а желаемое поведение. Говоря про ход мысли я имел в виду её ход по направлению к получению решения, то есть как это можно реализовать используя ваши тэги - php/jquery.

Answer (score 1):

**Решение на чистом JS:**

В CSS мы пишем класс `.disabled`, в котором запрещаем действия (`pointer-events:none`)

По клику на кнопку мы вызываем функцию `Test()` внутри которой после того как мы выполняем действия, мы добавляем класс `.disabled` к нашей кнопке, предварительно получив её из DOM по её `id` при помощи `document.getElementById`.

Теперь нам осталось убрать этот класс через 15 минут - для этого мы запускаем таймер `setTimeout`

*я поставил 3 секунды чтобы можно было быстро увидеть что кнопка через временной промежуток снова становится активной. чтобы было 15 минут поставьте туда значение 900000*

```js
function Test() {

  var btn = document.getElementById('btn');  
  alert('Нажатие!');  
  btn.classList.add('disabled');
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    btn.classList.remove('disabled');
  }, 3000); //чтобы было 15 мин поставь 900000 вместо 3000

}
```

```css
.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onClick="Test()">Нажать!</button>
```

Comment: а как добавить сюда что бы куки сохранялись и при обновлении страницы человек не мог повторно нажать

Comment: @u_mulder точно, исправил

Comment: @GMG ну погуглите как с куками работать. Принцип тот же, устанавливаем куку, потом её удаляем через setTimeout. При загрузке страницы проверяем есть ли кука - если да, то вешаем .disabled, и запускаем таймер заново (когда таймер перестает работать, удаляем .disabled и куку)

Comment: В данном случае удобнее работать с localStorage, нежели с куками

Comment: @Crasher дело говоришь